# multiples of a number and greater than "a number" in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

list3 needs to contain values that are 10 times greater than the numbers from baseList that are multiples of 5 and greater than 50. How can I write that?

It needs to look like this:

> [550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]

```
def main():
    baseList = list(range(1, 101))

    list1 = [x for x in baseList if x % 2 == 0]
    print(list1)

    list2 = [x for x in baseList if x % 3 == 0 and x <= 50]
    print(list2)

    list3 = [x for x in baseList if x % 5 == 0 and x >= 50]
    print(list3)

main()
```

Comment: What is `baseList`?

Comment: Please follow proper Python style, variables should be in the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
baseList = list(range(1, 101))
print [10*x for x in baseList if x % 5 == 0 and x > 50]
```